# updating my js accordion tabs to selectively open and close content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an accordion in such a way that only 1 set of content can be open at any one time, my problem is how do I update my code so I can click the active tab and close the content? At the moment if I try to close the active tab the content slides up and then slides straight back down?

Im sure I've written this code in the wrong way and would appreciate all advice on how to enhance this http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/csggQ/1/

Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are over complicating things :)

You've kinda already made it, http://jsfiddle.net/csggQ/21/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').hide();

    $('h2').click(function() {

        if($(this).hasClass('active'))
        {
           $(this).removeClass('active');
           $(this).next('p').slideUp(600);
        } else {          
           $('#myContent .active').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(600);
           $(this).addClass('active');
           $(this).next('p').slideDown(600);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, yeah im trying to learn and def over complicating everything i do :s